# how can i assign only year say 2011 in a datetime variable in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a asp Text box as 
where the user will fill only a year value, For this value I have Datetime type Property in c# application and Date type column in DB. So I want to convert that txtYear.Text to DateTime But it will only hold and/or show the year. Please help me in this situation.

Comment: When you need only the year why store it as `DateTime` at all

Comment: @V4Vendetta You may have a `DateTime` property in your Model while you want to show only the year part of it in a ViewModel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A DateTime object will always hold a complete DateTime value, you can't use it to store a year only. (what use would that be anyway?) Besides, the datatype of a "year" is int, not DateTime.

So, I'd like to suggest changing your property to datatype int, both in your code and database.

Comment: Thnx Nico, I will change the type both in app ans db

Comment: This is probably a good idea also for dates (just-a-date, no time part) but I've never had the courage to do it.

Answer (score 8):

To display just the year use the format "yyyy".

```
        string s = "2011";
        DateTime d = new DateTime(int.Parse(s), 1, 1);


        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("yyyy"));
        Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Bypass Solution.

Answer (score 6):

You have to specify the format of the `DateTime` value you are manipulating:

```
String dateTimeFormat = "yyyy";
```

To show only a part of the `DateTime` value use the following:

```
dateTimeValue.ToString(dateTimeFormat);
```

To read a `String` value that represents a *year* into a `DateTime` use the following:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(stringValue, dateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

[DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

[DateTime.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a095fsay.aspx) converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent string representation.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than applying any string manipulating function make use of Year property. Check the documentation on the msdn by visiting below link.

[DateTime.Year Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A DateTime always has a full date component. When you create the DateTime instance, you'll need to assign a month and day, but you can ignore them in your usage.

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(int.Parse(txtYear.Text, 1, 1);

txtYear.Text = d.ToString("yyyy");
```

Even better would be not to use a DateTime but just use int. If you have only a year, you only need an int.

Answer (score 1):

i assume the text box name is txYear

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime (Convert.ToInt32(txYear.text),1,1)
```

save this dt value in database

Comment: thanx for this Bypass solution, I was looking for this. but from all the answers I come to conclusion that I should change the type to int or smallint, which is more convenient to deal with.

Comment: :) yes using as integer is better idea,but when u using datetime type you can use sql builtin function for manipulating datetime

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the year, why don't you make it of type `smallint`?

Anyway if you do really want to make it an year,

```
DateTime x = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.text), 1, 1);
```

But make sure you validate that `txtYear.text` actually does have a valid year.

Answer (score 0):

That is how I did and it worked.

```
string format = "yyyy";
        var CurrentYear = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
```